# PupeeteerSharp Does Not Work in ServiceFabric Stateless Service

Tags: puppeteer, azure-service-fabric, headless-browser, service-fabric-stateless, puppeteer-sharp

I am developing web crawler which could render Javascript websites and so I decided to use PupeeteerSharp, a .NET port of popular Node.JS headless Chrome browser Pupeeteer API. I am running Service Fabric's local development cluster on Windows 10 development machine and have one stateless service in my solution.

I've created `Data` folder under Service project's `PackageRoot` folder and put `.local-chromium` folder contents there (contains `chrome.exe` executable) so it deploys as independent data package of service.

I've also placed this XML config line in `ServiceManifest.xml` file:

`<DataPackage Name="Data" Version="1.0.0" />`

So far it looks good and headless browser content is copied to SFCluster Data package directory properly.

Then in my Stateless Service code I try to call Pupeeteer chromium executable as follows:

```
var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions
{
   Headless = true,
   ExecutablePath = _chromiumPath // @$"{context.CodePackageActivationContext.GetDataPackageObject("Data").Path}\.local-chromium\Win64-706915\chrome-win\chrome.exe"
});

using (var page = (await browser.NewPageAsync()))
{
   Response renderResponse;
try
{
   renderResponse = await page.GoToAsync(webPage.AbsoluteUri, timeout);

   if (renderResponse.Status != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
   {
      return new RenderResult(RenderStatus.OtherFailure);
   }
     // other code
   }
catch (TimeoutException)
{
   return new RenderResult(RenderStatus.Timeouted);
}
```

In this line: `using (var page = (await browser.NewPageAsync()))` my code (Thread) simply hangs without returning, in Debug console I see many thread exits, but no exception occurs. I was previously getting System.IO.FileNotFoundException when I was fixing some other errors regarding appropriate copying of chromium folder contents, but now these errors are gone so it seems that code find .exe but somehow cannot start headless mode of PupeeterSharp.

Does that mean that I cannot simply run external .exe chromium binary with Service Fabric's Native Application Model? Should I use Docker and Linux containers instead?

Comment: Could you try adding `ConfigureAwait(false)` in all your awaits? I'm not saying that's the solution but worth checking.

Comment: @hardkoded thank you for your comment, unfortunately, nothing changed after placing these in code. However, I see in TaskManager that Chromium process starts but again, Debug console shows a lot of Thread exits with code 0.

Comment: Could you try connecting a logger? see https://github.com/hardkoded/puppeteer-sharp/issues/856#issuecomment-458104699

Comment: @hardkoded tried to generate dump, as I try with ConsoleApp it's being generated (also in standalone console app Puppeteer is working), but somehow when I run the same code in cluster service I do not see any dump file at all.

Comment: Does the crawler interact with the desktop? (does it show anything)

Comment: @LoekD no, I try to start puppeteer in headles mode, the process is shown in taskmanager, though.

Comment: Why not run it as a Guest Executable and do Puppeteer.ConnectAsync, instead of launching it? This way service fabric will manage it (if it crashes, it'll restart it and so on).

Comment: @FrancescCastells good point, tried to wrap it as guest executable, but somehow cannot launch that service correctly. Console dumps gives this chromium error `[0516/110208.797:FATAL:crashpad_win.cc(81)] Check failed: base::CreateDirectoryAndGetError(metrics_path, nullptr)`

Comment: @FrancescCastells Edit: found issue, the default `NetworkService` permission rights under which Fabric host is running, was not enough to launch chromium process. So assigned Administrator rights via `<Principals>` XML tag in `ApplicationManifest.xml` file and now it launches correctly.

Comment: Nice. See if you can get the whole set up working.